# Guava biMap for bi directional map, but do we have any thread safe bi directional map?

Tags: java, bimap

Guava biMap for bi directional map, but do we have any thread safe bi directional map ?

Answer (score 1):

There is [`Maps.synchronizedBiMap(BiMap)`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#synchronizedBiMap-com.google.common.collect.BiMap-) in Guava which provides some conditional level of thread-safety. The JavaDoc warns that you will have to manually synchronize on the map when using any of the views.

You could also use an [`ImmutableBiMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableBiMap.html) which should be thread-safe.